# Android Studio minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion warning

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

In an Android project that I have, I have this section in the build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19;
    }
}
```

On the 'minSdkVersion' and 'targetSdkVersion' properties, there are the warnings:

```
'minSdkVersion' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'

'targetSdkVersion' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)`
```

Is this a bug, or something else?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the section of code that you have included. Remove the semicolon but that is not the cause of issue it should work fine. AFAIK there is no such bug in AS so include your complete build script in question.

Comment: Remove ; after targetSdkVersion

Comment: Android Studio Bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65202  Duplicate of http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug, but I don't have a bug number for it. The syntax checking for **build.gradle** files is incomplete, and this warning is spurious. Please ignore it.